# Center 3 images in a div Bootrstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I make this 3 images to be in center of the page with Bootstrap? 
my code:

```
<div id="small-img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pagination-centered footer-bottom-img">
    <ul>
       <li>
         <img class="img-responsive inline-block center-block" alt="" src="ssl_secure.png">
       </li>
        <li>
           <img class="img-responsive inline-block center-block" alt="" src="secure-cc-paypal.png">
        </li>
        <li>
           <img class="img-responsive inline-block center-block" alt="" src="gt-secured-seal.gif">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the image to be aligned in the center of the page, you just have to add `text-center` `class` to the containing div.

```
<div id="small-img" class="text-center col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 pagination-centered footer-bottom-img">
  <ul >
    <li>
        <img class="img-responsive inline-block center-block" alt="" src="ssl_secure.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="img-responsive inline-block center-block" alt="" src="secure-cc-paypal.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="img-responsive inline-block center-block" alt="" src="gt-secured-seal.gif">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### [check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jpynode/1/)

Comment: even if i add text-center to the div all 3 images are align to the left of the page not in the middle

Comment: true, very strange, anyway thank you very much for your answer and your help

Comment: my best guess is you probably have styling that is messing up with that div.  @RobertD